# Laravel4: Validation on file entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, validationerror

I have in my app a simple form to upload photo.

There are three fields: title - caption - and the button for choosing the file.
Right now the validation check if the title is required.
The caption is not required and is ok.

But i do not know how can i deal with validation regarding files.

If no file is inserted, i get the laravel error message: Call to a member function move() on a non-object.
Instead i would like just a validation error.
And how can i required that only images are entered?
Right now is possible to upload even word documents..

There are the rules as they are now. In the Photo model:

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array('title' => 'required');
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well 1st of all your `$rules` should be in `Photos` Model not in the controller , 2nd to make a file required you do it like so :

```
$rules = array(
  'file'=>'image',
 );
```

you can add more rules like max file size like so :

```
$rules = array(
  'file'=>'image|max:2000',
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Two questions:
1 - now when a non-image is inserted, is not uploaded anymore, but i get a laravel error, while i would like to obtain just a validation error.
2 - How can i make that the image is required?
I try to add this required:
public static $rules = array('title' => 'required', 'image' => ' required | image | max:2000');

But is not working

Comment: 1- You will get your validation errors if the validation fails , you can return it as json or whatever you like. 2- its `$rules = array('title' => 'required', 'file' => ' required | image | max:2000');`

Comment: Yes. The problem was tring to move the uploaded file even if there was nothing, and gave the laravel error.